# " X not distributed as " notation

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

A question about notation:

We sometimes use ∼ to denote "distributed as" e.g. if X is Gaussian we write X∼N(μ,σ2).

How to denote that X  may not belong to Gaussian distribution N(μ,σ2).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I would like to know how to represent mathematically (not just to write in latex)

Comment: Just cross out $\sim$

Comment: $X \not\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$